# How to join 2 Models in Django using 2 common columns?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have 2 tables in Django, one for stock data and another for stock metadata. The date and ticker together are unique in each model,

```
class BulkData(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()    
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    type = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
    exchange_short_name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    MarketCapitalization = models.DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=2)
    request_exchange = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   

class ohlcdata(models.Model):
    
    date = models.DateField()
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)

    open = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5, null = True)
    high = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5, null = True)
    low = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5, null = True)
    close = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5, null = True)
    volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=0, null = True)
```

I need todo a join operation on date and ticker and right now I'm using a raw SQL query.

```
query3 = "SELECT * FROM stocklist_bulkdata LEFT JOIN stocklist_ohlcdata ON `stocklist_bulkdata`.`date` = `stocklist_ohlcdata`.`date` AND `stocklist_bulkdata`.`ticker` = `stocklist_ohlcdata`.`ticker` WHERE `stocklist_bulkdata`.`date` = '2023-03-30'"

qs3 = BulkData.objects.raw(query3)
```

How can I do this using Django QuerySet instead of raw SQL query?

Tried using raw SQL query, looking to do this using Django QuerySet

Comment: The simplest thing to do would probably be to change BulkData to have a [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to ohlcdata, or vice versa. You could maybe use [FilteredRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects), but I don't know if that works for models without a relation.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BulkData(models.Model):
  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)



class ohlcdata(models.Model):
     name=models.ForeignKey(BulkData, related_name="bulknames", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now the BulkData and ohlcdata are related with the name bulknames , you can access any bulkdata using ohlcdata or vice versa